# Android KITKAT (4.0.3 API 15) View.startDrag() throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

View.startDrag throws NPE and this is happening to me for Android API 15 but not API 22.

This issue is very easy to reproduce. Open Android Studio, create a template project with one blank activity using API 15. Adding the following logic to the floating action button:

```
        fab.setOnLongClickListener(
            new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    v.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("", ""), new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
```

The stacktrace for the error is the following:

```
E/View: Unable to initiate drag
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:77)
        at android.view.View.startDrag(View.java:13869)
        at test.dragdroptest.MainActivity$2.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:3827)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:14571)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Not sure what I did wrong here. I have been fighting this issue for two days and there is not much resource online about this. I cannot believe no one else had ran into the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it only happens on the device I used for testing but not from emulator with the same API level. I guess there is no way I can get away from this issue :(